# Why does validating a binary tree require +1 and -1 at the final stage?

Tags: python, binary-tree

This is an efficient solution for checking a binary tree:

```
# Return true if the given tree is a BST and its values
# >= min and <= max
def isBSTUtil(node, mini, maxi):

    # An empty tree is BST
    if node is None:
        return True

    # False if this node violates min/max constraint
    if node.data < mini or node.data > maxi:
        return False

    # Otherwise check the subtrees recursively
    # tightening the min or max constraint
    return (isBSTUtil(node.left, mini, node.data -1) and
          isBSTUtil(node.right, node.data+1, maxi))
```

Taken from: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/a-program-to-check-if-a-binary-tree-is-bst-or-not/

I'm testing it against a tree from https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-is-binary-search-tree
and of course, it works.

[image: Binary Tree]

However, I really don't understand why the final stage replaces maxi with node.data -1 and mini with node.data+1. Why does it add or subtract 1? In the previous conditional we have already checked that it is lower or higher.

I've tried removing them, and the hackerrank automated tests won't pass. But I really don't understand why the extra addition of 1 and subtraction of 1 is needed on top of the replacement. I tried doing a full stack trace with a pencil and paper on the far left-most branch which looks like:

```
isBST(4, -99999, 99999)
(ok, ok, ok)
isBST(2, -99999, 4)
(ok, ok, ok)
isBST(1, -99999, 2)
(ok, ok, ok)
True
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: In BST you cannot have a value from the node also present in its subtrees.

Comment: Ah so this stops duplication?

Comment: It renders tree `(3, A, nil); A=(3, nil, nil)` as not BST. If that is what you mean, then yes.

Comment: You may be able to remove the +/-1 if you change the range test to `node.data <= mini or node.data >= maxi`.